# How store mail and username in parse from FBapi

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, authentication, parse-platform

i'm trying to build the facebook connection on my app (iOs 9+) with Parse and the facebook API.

I'm using the PFLogInViewController to make it but when i procces to the creation of user he doesn't store the real first_name or mail of the user. I'm data i've only a random string in username, main is undefined, and a facebook authData. I really want to store at the creation the first name, the gender... I can't found how..

```
 if (Utils.notLoggedIn()) {
        let loginViewController = PFLogInViewController()
        loginViewController.facebookPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
        loginViewController.delegate = self
        loginViewController.fields = [.Facebook]
        self.presentViewController(loginViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```